# Char 2D Array treats characters separately

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char

Am I able to get the whole number out of char table? For example:

```
char *table[]={"A","123","2"};
```

I want to display number 123, but whenever i call

```
cout<<*table[1];
```

I get

```
1
```

Am I able to fix this ?

Comment: Did you try just `table[1]`?

Comment: It works, by why ? How it differs from *table[1]?

Comment: And i need to operate on *table[], because the function main have such parameters. I tried to strcpy it on the other table but it said the types dont match each other

Comment: `table[1]` is the char string. `*table[1]` is the first char only.

Comment: So am I able to convert this char **table[] = { argv[0],"K","13","*","12", "+", "1"}; , into char table[]={....}; ?

Comment: `char *table[]` is an array of char strings (actually an array of pointers to chars).  `char table[]` is an array of single chars. So no.

Comment: @Mikkey put code into backticks `\`like this\`` to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

When writing char `*table[]={"A","123","2"}`, your declaring an array of char pointers. In a sense this is a 2 dimensional array and you would print "123" using:

```
for( unsigned i=0; table[j][i]!='\0'; ++i )    //given j = 1                        
{                                            
    cout << table[j][i];
}
```

Output:

```
123
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at an [operator precedence table for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you will find that array subscripting `[]` is higher precedence than pointer dereferencing `*`. This, then, is what is happening.

`table` is an array of pointers. The pointers in the array point to the first character of a string. The next character in the string is simply the next char in memory. The end of the string is the first character whose value is (as an integer) 0, called the null terminator.

When you access `table[1]`, you get the element in the array at index 1, a pointer to a char, which represents a string. When you access `*table[1]`, you get the element in the array at index 1, a pointer to a char, and then dereference that pointer, to get the char it points to.